# Embedding an InfoPath form within a SharePoint page

Tags: 2007, infopath, browser-compatibility

I have a working document library that uses a template content type, which is an InfoPath form. I have enabled the browser compatibility settings and the "view form in browser" option in the document library settings. With these settings, I can get to the normal browser-based form by clicking New. This opens a new window with the form between two gray bars with buttons on them.

I'm interested in embedding this form in a SharePoint page, preferably without the gray bars so the only submit option is my button.

Is this possible? I'm thinking that it may be possible to embed it in a web part? That would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolbar and various options are all part of what is configured in the form's options.  If you want to display the form on a web part page, simply reference it in a Web Page Viewer web part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Web Page Viewer web part. Where do I configure the "form's options" related to the gray bar and buttons? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow Nick Grattan's PDF document "How to Host Microsoft InfoPath Forms in SharePoint 2007 Web Part Pages" found here:

http://www.nickgrattan.net/Publications/How%20to%20Host%20Microsoft%20InfoPath%20Forms%20in%20SharePoint%20Pages.pdf

You don't need to do this for 2010 as the control is already there, just add it to the page.

Hope that helps.